# Why is my image not being appended to the array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've a simple model that includes:

```
var photos: [UIImage]?
```

I've copied the file zombies.jpg as a file into the project. Then, in a required init in a Table View Controller, I want to load a dummy record. I can define all the String and NSDate properties, but when I try to append photos:

```
dummyRecord1.photos?.append(UIImage(named: "zombies.jpg")!)
print(UIImage(named: "zombies.jpg"))
print(dummyRecord1.photos)
```

The console shows that the image is there, but it never gets into the array:

```
Optional(<UIImage: 0x7f8fd14b4c40>, {2592, 1936})nil
```

Comment: where did you initialize photos array, I think its still nil

Comment: Did you ever create the array? Or did you just declare the variable?

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise I couldn't append a nil array. Both answers are solutions, so I accepted the one with the clearer explanation and upvoted the other straight forward answer. Much appreciated both.

Comment: Why do you use an optional array at all? An empty array would be in many cases sufficient: `var photos = [UIImage]()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have initialize photos array, and you are using conditional unwrapping, which means if its not nil append but your photos array is nil at the time so it will not append a photo in nil array. You should do something like this `var photos:[UIImage] = []`

Answer (score 3):

Better do this:

```
var photos : [UIImage?] = []
```

It initializes an empty array, that is ready to store `UIImage` objects.