# Appending image o array from imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift

I have an empty array of images like so:

```
var arrayOfImages : [UIImage?]?
```

Now I want to append the selected image to the array after being selected by the user.  But for some reason, it doesn't seem to want to append. The print statement where the breakpoint is returns nil everytime

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let indexpathForCell = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let uploadImagesCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpathForCell) as! UploadImagesCell

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        arrayOfImages?.append(editedImage)
        print(arrayOfImages?[0]) //breakpoint here
    }
```

Although, if i was to do it like this:

```
var arrayOfImages = [UIImage?]()
```

and append the image into the array, it would work fine.  With what i'm trying to achieve afterwards with the array, i feel I need to array to be an optional

Answer (score 1):

Solved after finding this: [Why is my image not being appended to the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005189/why-is-my-image-not-being-appended-to-the-array)

With this:

```
var arrayOfImages : [UIImage?]? = []
```

It seems I needed to initialise the empty array

Answer (score 0):

Please declare like as below, sure it's work and it is optional array

```
var arrayOfImages : [UIImage]? = [UIImage]()
```